# Can't see my mouse pointer while playing full screen on some games

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mouse

I have been running Windows 10 for a while and I recently tried to launch an old game that I haven't played in ages (Minecraft). For some reason I can navigate on the menu, but I can't see where I'm clicking. My mouse is invisible, but only when the game is in full screen.

**Things I've already tried:**

- Disabling pointer trail and everything related to areo (back to basic)
- Creating another user (in case my account was corrupted)
- Changing my resolution to minimum than lunch the game
- Updating my mouse drivers (R.A.T.S 5)
- Updating my graphic card's drivers
- Troubleshooting the game
- Running the game as administrator
- Trying on another monitor

I have no idea what else I could try to see my mouse while playing Minecraft;  otherwise it's very hard to play.

Answer (score 6):

This *can* be caused by a setting in the "f.lux" software (at least, it was for me). This could be fixed if you turn off "Software mouse cursor when needed (fixes "white cursor").

Answer (score 2):

Can I just say I restarted minecraft with no changes and it worked. If the suggestions before didnt help, sometimes restarting might just do the job

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I found out that it was caused by the pointer trails being displayed. If you have that setting enabled, try disabling it as it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by **disabling** the **Discord Overlay** for the game.

Comment: The first step here is to ask the OP if they use Discord. As it is, this should be a comment.

Comment: How is this not an answer? It's providing a possible solution, just like the other three answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch Minecraft in the Compatibility Mode with another version of Windows. Simply right click on the icon of Minecraft and click on Properties. Then, go to Compatibility and turn it on, select the version you want, but I recommend NOT to go lower than Windows XP.